# Open Excel file after WIX installation

Tags: c#, wix, installation

I am using WiX SDK to create an installer. After the installer finish I would like to open an Excel file (.xls) using the bellow code. I can see the file in installation folder.Unfortunatelly nothing happens after end of installation.

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#test.xls]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchFile" 
    BinaryKey="WixCA" 
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="yes" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action='LaunchFile' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem most probably is that the value of properties are not of type `Formatted`, but are simple strings that won't be evaluated. Check the following comment on the [site for the `Property`-table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Note that you cannot use the Property table to set a property to the value of another property. The installer does nothing to the text string entered in the Value column before setting the property in the Property column. If FirstProperty is entered into the Property column and [SecondProperty] in the Value column, the value of FirstProperty is set to the text string "[SecondProperty]" and not to the value of the SecondProperty property. This is necessary to prevent creating circular references in the Property table. Instead, you can set one property to another by using a Custom Action Type 51.

You can check if the custom action would run normally if you enter the whole path to your Excel-file as value for your property.
To enable the wanted behavior you have to use another custom action that will set the value to the path of your Excel-file, then it should work as expected.